# unexpected title bar behavior in WPF RibbonWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ribbon

i am using the Microsoft ribbon control.
i need to merge the ribbon title bar and the window title bar but i get very bad results as it is shown in below picture. Also what i need is in the picture.

please provide me the solution for these:

- the title bar to be usual as other applications like paint.
- show the quick access toolbar items in title bar

thank you

[image]

the code in xaml is as below:

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow
    x:Uid="RibbonWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
    xmlns:telerikDocking="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking" x:Class="WpfRibbonApplication1.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow"
    x:Name="RibbonWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">
<Grid x:Uid="LayoutRoot" x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Uid="RowDefinition_1" Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Uid="RowDefinition_2" Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ribbon:Ribbon x:Uid="Ribbon" x:Name="Ribbon" Title="Ribbon Title">
        <ribbon:Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
            <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Uid="ribbon:RibbonButton_1" Content="1" />
        </ribbon:Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
        <ribbon:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
            <ribbon:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar x:Uid="ribbon:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar_1" >
                <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Uid="QATButton1" x:Name="QATButton1" 
                    Content="2" />
                <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Uid="QATButton2" x:Name="QATButton2" 
                    Content="3" />
            </ribbon:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
        </ribbon:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
        <ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu x:Uid="ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu_1">
                <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem1" Header="Hello _Ribbon"
                    x:Name="MenuItem1"
                                                   />
            </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <ribbon:RibbonTab x:Uid="HomeTab" x:Name="HomeTab" 
            Header="Home">
        </ribbon:RibbonTab>
    </ribbon:Ribbon>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

> show the quick access toolbar items in title bar

To show the Items you need to import the icons in your project. After that you need to refer the icons in your RibbonButton, I used here the **SmallImageSource** Property.

```
<ribbon:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
        <ribbon:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar x:Uid="ribbon:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar_1" >
            <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Uid="QATButton1" x:Name="QATButton1" 
                Content="2" SmallImageSource="Images/YourIcon_1.png" />
            <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Uid="QATButton2" x:Name="QATButton2" 
                Content="3" SmallImageSource="Images/YourIcon_2.png" />
        </ribbon:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
    </ribbon:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
```